# some API to reference a web page

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I'm working in a JavaEE7 project (built with Maven, but that's not the subject here) with 2 modules:

- `project-web` where I have some JSF pages with their corresponding `@ManagedBean`, which are responsible to communicate with a `Services` layer in the other module (a classic [MVC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) by the way)
- `project-model` where I have `Menu` and `Operation` objects. In the first I have a `List<Operation>` property and in the second I need a property (called  `relativeUrl`) to reference a `path/to/file.xhtml` file of the other module (among other properties in both)

Both `Menu` and `Operation` are `@Entity` objects (they are persisted into a DB). The idea is the following: a user logs into the System and according to the user profile, I have to retrieve the allowed operations with the corresponding menus and build the view in the `project-web` module

Is there any class, API or something else to manage and save the `relativeUrl` property?. I could use a plain `String` but I think that's quite error prone and hard to maintain.

Also, I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one doing something like this, so I presume there's something made in this matter.

Any help or guide is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is error-prone or hard to maintain about saving partial urls as a string? What do you expect to be doing with the relativeUrl other than saving and fetching it as-is?

Comment: To make an analogy: in JPA the Criteria API is type-safe, while JPQL is not, that's the error-prone part. Hard to maintain because if I move a webpage in the package, I must change the corresponding cell in the DB (by hand). I was thinking in something like the [Files API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) but to manage paths to files packaged in a war file. I'm now using String fields for `relativeUrl` with navigation rules configured in JSF, reducing the length of the "url" with a "logical name". I was wondering if there is a better approach.